# ItemsSource bindable property

Tags: xamarin, binding, xamarin.forms, itemssource

I'm trying to make `ContentView` with 2 items (`Label` and `DatePicker`) and I need to send `ItemsSource` for second item as bindable property.

I tried to use `BindingBase`, but it didn't work.

**Xaml**:

```
<Grid>
    <Label
        Text="Text"
        TextColor="Black"
        VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" />

    <controls:ExtendedPicker
        Title="Title"
        HorizontalOptions="End"
        ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding PickerItemDisplayBinding, Source={x:Reference This}}"
        ItemsSource="{Binding PickerItemsSource, Source={x:Reference This}}"
        SelectedIndex="{Binding PickerSelectedIndex, Source={x:Reference This}}" />
</Grid>
```

**Xaml.cs**:

```
public static readonly BindableProperty PickerItemsSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    "PickerItemsSource",
    typeof(IList),
    typeof(DetailedPicker));

public static readonly BindableProperty PickerSelectedIndexProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    "PickerSelectedIndex",
    typeof(int),
    typeof(DetailedPicker));

public static readonly BindableProperty PickerItemDisplayBindingProperty = BindableProperty.Create(
    "PickerItemDisplayBinding",
    typeof(BindingBase),
    typeof(DetailedPicker));


public IList PickerItemsSource
{
    get => (IList) GetValue(PickerItemsSourceProperty);
    set => SetValue(PickerItemsSourceProperty, value);
}

public int PickerSelectedIndex
{
    get => (int) GetValue(PickerSelectedIndexProperty);
    set => SetValue(PickerSelectedIndexProperty, value);
}

public BindingBase PickerItemDisplayBinding
{
    get => (BindingBase) GetValue(PickerItemDisplayBindingProperty);
    set => SetValue(PickerItemDisplayBindingProperty, value);
}
```

How can I bind `ItemsSource` as `BindableProperty` for `ContentView`?

Comment: Did you use INotifyPropertyChange?

Comment: @AlanJonesRios, yes, it works, when I use my Picker without content view, but when I'm trying to send `ItemsSource` as `BindableProperty`  it's not.

Comment: hard to tell without full code, but from what you have shown possibly because the bindable properties have the wrong type?

the declared properties use DetailedPicker, but in the xaml you are using ExtendedPicker

Comment: Try changing the type of your list to "ObservableCollection". I don't know if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can use `x:Reference` to the `this` keyword. I've never heard about such a thing.

Although I guess you can work around it, by giving a `x:Name` to your ContentView. Just like this:

```
<ContentView xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:Your.Controls.Namespace;assembly=packageName"
             x:Class="Your.Another.Control.Namespace.DetailedPicker"
             x:Name="MyThisReference">
    <ContentView.Content>
        <Grid>
            <!-- Your label and picker goes here -->
            <!-- ... -->
                         ItemsSource="{Binding PickerItemsSource, Source={x:Reference MyThisReference}}"
            <!-- ... -->
        </Grid>
    </ContentView.Content>
</ContentView>
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Needs one help I have done the same as you did but when I have pass PickerItemsSource="{Binding Path=FacilityVM.Locations}" PickerItemDisplayBinding="{Binding Name}" In Name give error name not found error ,Can you please help me

Comment: Sure, @JasminSojitra can you share the link of your question with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?